# Perform class method on Class object

Tags: objective-c, class, selector

I've got an instance of the `Class` class, obtained by calling the `class` method (example below). With that instance i'd like to call a class (`+ ..`) method on that.

**Callee**

```
Class foo = [FooBar class];
SEL selector = @selector(doSomething:)
// Call somehow?
```

**FooBar Definition**

```
@implementation FooBar

+ (void)doSomething:(id)argument { .. }

@end
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why your trying to invoke the method like that and not simply [FooBar doSomething:@"blah"];

Comment: Everything that is stored in a variable can be decided at runtime unlike constants.

Comment: There is no "Class class". `Class` is simply a generic type that can take a pointer to any class object, similar to how `id` is a generic type that can take a pointer to any object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Class foo = [FooBar class];
[foo doSomething];
```

Comment: Oh my, how could I possibly not try that?! Thanks :)